# Can't multiply sequence by 'float' on Inverse Matrix Function (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, list, matrix, floating-point

I'm trying to make a function that inverses entered 4 x 4 matrix

I am not allowed to use module or array, only 'list' and 'nested list comprehension'are allowed to use

This is all of my script based on Gaussian Jordan Elimination

```
matrix=[]
i=0

for i in range(4):
    row= []
    a,b,c,d=input("Enter the row: ").split()
    row.append(float(a))
    row.append(float(b))
    row.append(float(c))
    row.append(float(d))


    matrix.append(row)

print ("The matrix you entered : ","\n")

for row in matrix:
    print((row))

def inverse(matrix):
    Default=[[1,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0],
             [0,0,0,1]]

    Default[1]-=float(matrix[1][0]/matrix[0][0])*Default[0]
    Default[2]-=float(matrix[2][0]/matrix[0][0])*Default[0]
    Default[3]-=float(matrix[3][0]/matrix[0][0])*Default[0]

    matrix[1]-=float(matrix[1][0]/matrix[0][0])*matrix[0]
    matrix[2]-=float(matrix[2][0]/matrix[0][0])*matrix[0]
    matrix[3]-=float(matrix[3][0]/matrix[0][0])*matrix[0]

    Default[2]-=(matrix[2][1]/matrix[1][1])*Default[1]
    Default[3]-=(matrix[3][1]/matrix[1][1])*Default[1]
    matrix[2]-=(matrix[2][1]/matrix[1][1])*matrix[1]
    matrix[3]-=(matrix[3][1]/matrix[1][1])*matrix[1]

    Default[3]-=(matrix[3][2]/matrix[2][2])*Default[2]
    matrix[3]-=(matrix[3][2]/matrix[2][2])*matrix[2]

    Default[3]=Default[3]/(matrix[3][3])
    matrix[3]=matrix[3]/(matrix[3][3])

    Default[2]-=Default[3]*(matrix[2][3])
    Default[1]-=Default[3]*(matrix[1][3])
    Default[0]-=Default[3]*(matrix[0][3])
    matrix[2]-=matrix[3]*(matrix[2][3])
    matrix[1]-=matrix[3]*(matrix[1][3])
    matrix[0]-=matrix[3]*(matrix[0][3])

    Default[2]=Default[2]/(matrix[2][2])
    matrix[2]=matrix[2]/(matrix[2][2])

    Default[1]-=Default[2]*(matrix[1][2])
    Default[0]-=Default[2]*(matrix[0][2])
    matrix[1]-=matrix[2]*(matrix[1][2])
    matrix[0]-=matrix[2]*(matrix[0][2])

    Default[1]=Default[1]/(matrix[1][1])
    matrix[1]=matrix[1]/(matrix[1][1])

    Default[0]-=Default[1]*(matrix[0][1])
    matrix[0]-=matrix[1]*(matrix[0][1])

    Default[0]=Default[0]/(matrix[0][0])
    matrix[0]=matrix[0]/(matrix[0][0])

    return Default

print(inverse(matrix))
```

I'm not sure whether my approach is correct or not, and even this script crashes with [Typeerror:Can't multiply sequence by  'float']

Is there anyone knows what should I fix on the code? I'll really appreciate for your help

Comment: No, your approach is not correct. [Try looking at this code](https://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply a list by floating point number. That doesn't work the way you intend(It doesn't perform elementwise multiplication).

even this would throw same error :

`float(3)*[1,2]`.

You should make following changes :

```
Default[1]-= [float(matrix[1][0]/matrix[0][0])*i for i in Default[0]]
```

at respective places.